# What is this white sheet behind the insulation?

Tags: insulation

Was in a house this weekend with a little bit of insulation. Behind it was a white sheet that i haven’t seen before. Is it a vapor barrier?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a vapor barrier, but a poorly installed one... maybe just because of the window. This room looks like it's going to be a bathroom of some sort.

Comment: Yes it’s a bathroom. My assumption is they’re not finished hence the incomplete installation.

Comment: The insulation was placed there because after the big tub is installed it will be inaccessible.and the white plastic is a “finished” wall surface for under the tub.